# How to list the member name and address whose memberships are due for renewal?

Tags: sql, oracle

I get this error messages 'missing right parenthesis' as using following sql query:

```
SELECT G_MEMBERSHIP.MEMBER_ID, DATE_ADD(G_MEMBERSHIP.RENEWAL_DATE,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  WHERE G_MEMBERSHIP.RENEWAL_DATE > CURDATE()
FROM G_MEMBERSHIP
INNER JOIN G_MEMBER
ON G_MEMBERSHIP.MEMBER_ID = G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I'm using Oracle SQL developer

Comment: According to the functions you are using MySQL

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I no hv idea, can help me convert to oracle?

Comment: `select @@version` gives you a version or an error?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz an error with '"missing expression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT G_MEMBERSHIP.MEMBER_ID,add_months(G_MEMBERSHIP.RENEWAL_DATE,12)  
FROM G_MEMBERSHIP
INNER JOIN G_MEMBER
ON G_MEMBERSHIP.MEMBER_ID = G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID
WHERE G_MEMBERSHIP.RENEWAL_DATE > current_date
```

---

P.s.

`+ INTERVAL '1'` is risky

e.g.

```
select date '2012-02-29' + INTERVAL '1' YEAR from dual;
```

> ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified

```
select add_months (date '2012-02-29',12) from dual
```

> 2013-02-28 00:00:00

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE` goes AFTER `JOIN`

```
SELECT G_MEMBERSHIP.MEMBER_ID, DATE_ADD(G_MEMBERSHIP.RENEWAL_DATE,INTERVAL 1 YEAR)  
FROM G_MEMBERSHIP
INNER JOIN G_MEMBER
  ON G_MEMBERSHIP.MEMBER_ID = G_MEMBER.MEMBER_ID
WHERE G_MEMBERSHIP.RENEWAL_DATE > CURDATE()
```

Comment: OK, but still missing right parenthesis what problem?